# Set properties of extJs htmleditor

Tags: extjs, html-editor

I have a text box and there is some text written on it. Now, when somebody clicks inside the text box, I open a html editor (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.HtmlEditor) and now i want to place the text written inside the text box to come in the html editor so that user can edit it easily and save it. Similarly, when i open the html editor i want to update the value inside the color box and font-size and font-value in the html editor. Assume that i can fetch these values from the textbox. I tried googling it but could not found how to do this.

```
    Ext.QuickTips.init();  // enable tooltips
    new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: 'text-editor',
    id: 'html-editor',
    width: 440,
    height: 100,
    frame: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'htmleditor',
            enableColors: true,
            enableAlignments: true
        }
    ]
});


    $('#selected-text-box').click(function() {
    showEditor(this.id);
    //TODO: Write code here to set the properties of editor with the properties set in textbox
});
```

Now, i just want to ask. how to access the fields of html editor and set their value.

Comment: Googling is good. What have you tried as far as code goes?

Comment: Updated the code. Major problem i am facing is in setting the font-size of htmleditor according to font size in my text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I will work but about font-size I don't know

```
var Content = $('#' + textBoxId).html();
editor.setValue(Content);
```

I have tried this. It works :)